# Previewing Pictures within Orgmode (without exporting)

Tags: org-mode

It is already possible to preview equations in orgmode using images.  For example if I type

```
$y=2^x$
```

Then I can preview this equation within the org file itself.  My question is it possible to do this with images?  So far implementing

```
$\includegraphics{picture.png}$
```

doesn't work (I just get a blank box).

Comment: Does the file show correctly when you just visit it outside org-mode?

Answer (score 17):

You can insert an org link to your picture, with:

```
 [[file:/path/to/picture.png]]
```

And from there, <kbd>C-c C-x C-v</kbd> will toggle its display in the buffer, as mentionned [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html#fnd-6).

You can configure the variable `org-startup-with-inline-images` for startup behaviour.

Comment: Also try `C-c C-l` to insert file interactively~~